# Killing a running sh script using pid

Tags: bash, sh

I have made an Auto Clicker and was wondering how i would kill it using 
kill [pid]

**My auto Clicker works like this:**

```
while true [1]; do
   xdotool click --repeat 10000 --delay 150 1
done
```

**code I have used to try and terminate running proccess:**

```
ps -ef | grep AutoClicker | grep -v grep | xargs kill -9
```

I found this code on another post, however i have had no luck with it.

Comment: Is your script named mytestscript.php?

Comment: no my script is named AutoClicker, in my actual code i have 'AutoClicker' in place of mytestscript.php @Blokje5

Comment: What do you see if you just run ps -ef  | grep AutoClicker?

Comment: or if you run `ps -ef | grep bash`

Comment: wolfgang 24359 24000 0 09:53 pts/4 00:00:00    grep --color=auto AutoClicker

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to `true`?  The `[1]` doesn't hurt anything I suppose, but it sure looks weird.  You might as well say `while true as the sky is blue`, or `while true false`, but it's more typical to just write `while true; do`

Answer (score 1):

`pkill -f AutoClicker` or `kill $(pgrep -f AutoClicker)`

Comment: Tried this but still no luck @funkyjelly, my bad it did work i just had the command inout incorrectly. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code:

```
ps -ef | grep AutoClicker | grep -v grep | xargs kill -9
```

you should get an error message from `kill`.

`kill` expects a list of process ids not usernames, times, and random strings.

You need to filter out everything except the pids with something like:

```
ps -ef | grep AutoClicker | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the process ID, use your own "PID file".  I'll demonstrate with `sleep` in place of `xdotool`.

```
echo $$ > /tmp/my.pid

while true [1]; do
   echo "clicking"
   sleep 5
done

# rm -f /tmp/my.pid
```

I can run this script in another terminal window or the background.  The important thing is that `/tmp/my.pid` contains the process ID of *this running script*.  You can stop it with:

```
kill $(</tmp/my.pid)
```

This interrupts the while-loop.  Need to figure out how to remove the PID file...